# How can I sum all same the values from table column?

Tags: php, mysql

I need sum all same values.
I have MySQL table **'members'** with these values e.g.:

```
name   staat
--------------------
John   United-states
Mary   United-states
Jan    Czech-republic
Paul   Slovakia
Julia  Slovakia
--------------------
```

I try make a array

```
$states = array(
        'United-states' => 'us',
        'Czech-republic' => 'cz',
        'Slovakia' => 'sk'
);
```

and SQL query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, `staat` FROM `members` GROUP BY `staat`");
foreach (mysqli_fetch_array($query) as $item) {
        ${'row_'.$states[$item['staat']]} = $item['count'];
}
```

Desired result for chart is:

```
$row_us (In my example '2')
$row_cz (In my example '1')
$row_sk (In my example '2')
```

All rows **$row_xx** is dynamic.

Comment: And the actual question/problem is what now, exactly?

Comment: FYI, you should really rather be using arrays, than variables named like `$row_us`, `$row_cz`, etc.

Comment: query not working...

Comment: And that again means what? Does it throw an error, do you get incorrect results, ...? Please go read [ask].

Comment: I get a warnings for query:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'count' in.... 
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'staat' in...
etc.

Comment: Actually I have 959 in table members from 11 countries.
E.g. when add new member from existing country (United-states), simply sum $row_us heighten about 1. (In my example sum 3)
But, when new member is from Spanien, then I modify only array (**'Spain' => 'es'**) and sql query create new column for Chart (graph) with new country **$row_es**.

Comment: _“I get a warnings for query”_ – those are not about the query itself, but about your PHP code that tries to access stuff like `$item['count'];` ... “Illegal string offset 'count'” here means that $item is not actually an array as you thought it was, but a mere string value. Use `var_dump` to find out what the variables you are dealing with actually contain, if you are not sure.